# How can i get post's gallery page url from excerpt? (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress

i want to get post's gallery page (attachments.php) url from blog excerpt.

i tried to explain with this
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpGl7.jpg)

and that is my codes

```html
<div style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0;">
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post-$post_attachment); ?>">Galeriye Git</a>
</div>
```

so how can do that?

Comment: Which theme you use?

Comment: Puzzle premium theme